# BigQuery 'TIMESTAMP(<date_string>)' returns epoch for invalid string parameter

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp

Is it correct behavior for BigQuery's `TIMESTAMP(<date_string>)` function to return epoch time instead of failing the query if the argument provided is not a valid `STRING`?

For example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(2015-06-30) as foo FROM [a_table]
```

..runs as being valid SQL and returns **1970-01-01 00:32:59 UTC**

Obviously, the argument is missing the enclosing quotes, so:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('2015-06-30') as foo FROM [a_table]
```

..now returns **2015-06-30 00:00:00 UTC**

Contrastingly, `PARSE_UTC_USEC(<date_string>)` which also expects a `STRING` parameter, complains when it's not a proper `STRING`:

```
SELECT PARSE_UTC_USEC(2015-06-30) as foo FROM [a_table]
```

> Error: Argument to PARSE_UTC_USEC must have type STRING but was int64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a lot of testing with this and it seems that indeed the behavior is as you explained it :

by default the TIMESTAMP() seems to take a string, but if it gets an int, it'll treat is as an int (I tried to TIMESTAMP(2011) and it gave me EPOCH + 33 minutes or so (it seems to pad your number)).

In any case, I assume both behaviors should be aligned, and this is not expected in some way. You can always file a defect report or feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list) to get the behavior documented or changed.

Comment: 2011 seconds is 33 minutes and 31 seconds... is it just adding that number of seconds to it?

Comment: indeed, but normally UTC is in milli, not in seconds, so it would have to have been padded with some 0s. Anyway the point is not the exact timestamp it's returning here, but the fact it's still giving something, when it should error out